# Connection flights with different airlines

Tags: tickets, connecting-flights, emirates, bangkok

when flying from manchester to Nha Trang and having two connecting flights one with  emirates and the other with Bangkok airways, how many boarding pass will i receive and when do I receive them and what will happen with my luggage?

Comment: For clarity, do you mean Manchester UK? Do you have a single booking (one PNR)?

Answer (score 1):

You *always* get one boarding pass *per plane* you enter.

If you booked it in on *one* ticket, you typically get all boarding passes at first check-in, and your luggage is nearly always checked through - if you bought separate tickets, it's *your* problem to every time pick your luggage up and check it in again, and get the further boarding passes.

Comment: @Dreamtraveller If you bought separate tickets, it’s also your problem if you miss any connections, irrespective of the reason for missing it.

Comment: If you buy one ticket, sometime you get one boarding pass per several planes. I have several examples (European airlines)